# why can't I use LCIDToLocaleName in gcc?

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc

I have a slight problem with gcc.

I want to use the winapi function `LCIDToLocaleName()` but althrough I included `windows.h` and run windows 7, gcc always complains: *'LCIDToLocaleName was not declared in this scope'*.

Is this function part of a namespace that I am not aware of? All other winapi functions I have used so far are working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows XP ?

Minimum supported OS is Vista :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: No - see post above. I am using windows 7. althrough the compilers seems to think I am using Vista as it says WINVER is defined as _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA (0x0600), still that should be enough ?!